# Unable to copy from JMeter 5.4.1

Tags: jmeter

I had been able to copy from my JMeter Summary Report to Excel for further analysis and the recently that stopped working.  Looking at other questions, I tried Force Quit the pboard and also changing the Look/Feel to system, but these were all suggestion on the V2.* series.  Any recent issues/fixes?  I am on a Macbook macOS Big Sur 11.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using JMeter 5.4.1 on MacOS 11.4 so it's either your local environmental problem of something introduces in 11.5.2

[image]

See [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) and MacOS log using i.e. [Concole app](https://support.apple.com/guide/console/welcome/mac), it might be the case you will find some suspicious entries helping to determine the root cause there.

In the meantime be aware that you can generate a CSV version of the summary report using `Save Table Data` button at the bottom of the Summary Report listener

[image]

or generate it out of the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) using [JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line) like:

```
./JMeterPluginsCMD.sh --generate-csv summary.csv --input-jtl /path/to/your/testresult.jtl --plugin-type SynthesisReport
```

Once done you should be able to [import it into Excel easily](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I had missed the Save Table Data button.  I just updated osMac Big Sur 11.5.2  as well and I can now copy as well.